# Is there a way to migrate via wordpress dashboard?

Tags: migration

I have a website on aws lightsail that I can no longer ssh into. I can login via wordpress but for some reason ssh is no longer working.

Is there a way to export my wordpress instance via the wordpress dashboard?

Comment: No. No there is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to a Backup WordPress plugin. They usually create a zip file with all files and DB.
Then you can download it and install it where you need to migrate too.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/backup/

You can also find some tools like https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager-advanced/ & https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-phpmyadmin-extension/ which can help you

Hope it will help